# How do you append dictionaries to dictionaries in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Is there a way to append a dictionary to another one?
I'm aware that you can create a dictionary with other's within it:

```py
father_dictionary={
'Dict1':{'a':'1','b':2,'c':3}
'Dict2':{'a':'4','b':5,'c':3}
}

mother_dictionary={
'Dict3':{'a':'6','b':7,'c':3}
```

but what if I wanted to append `Dict3` to `father_dictionary`, assuming that Dict3 is a key from `mother_dictionary`?

I've tried a bunch of stuff but I either get back an error telling me that

> 'dict' is an unhashable type or a syntax error.

Comment: `Dict3` is a *key*; `parent_dictionary['Dict3'] = {'a':'7','b':8,'c':9}` works just fine. `type 'dict' is unhashable` means you tried to use the dictionary object as a key.

Answer (score 7):

Simply assign the key-value pair to the existing dict, specifying the new key as the subscript and the new value as the right-hand-side of the assignment:

```
parent_dictionary['Dict3'] = {'a':'7', 'b': 8, 'c': 9}
```

**Edit for the updated question:**
To merge two dicts, use the `update` method. For example, to add *all* keys from `mother_dictionary` to `father_dictionary`, use:

```
father_dictionary.update(mother_dictionary)
```

To add a *single* key (and your question still doesn't make it clear if you need to add a single key or all keys), again make use of assignment:

```
father_dictionary['Dict3'] = mother_dictionary['Dict3']
```

Comment: +1. To add, one have to be careful if sharing the subdictionary via reference is fine or whether a copy should be made. It depends on how the `father_dictionary` is to be used. Both assignment and `update()` causes sharing the nested dictionary -- if `mother_dictionary['Dict3']` changes, the change will be visible also in the `father_dictionary['Dict3']`.

Comment: @pepr Agreed, about the sharing pitfall. I considered mentioning the potential issues with sharing, but it decided that it was somewhat outside the scope of this question. Given the submitter's lack of Python experience, he/she might be more confused than helped with an answer going into such details.

Answer (score 2):

Take this fragment of code:

```
>>> father_dictionary={
'Dict1':{'a':'1','b':2,'c':3},
'Dict2':{'a':'4','b':5,'c':3}
}
>>> mother_dictionary={
'Dict3':{'a':'6','b':7,'c':3}}
```

and update father_dictionary:

```
>>> father_dictionary.update(mother_dictionary)
```

test:

```
>>> father_dictionary.get('Dict3')
{'a': '6', 'b': 7, 'c': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, (and I hope this is just a copy-paste issue) your syntax is wrong.

Elements of a dictionary are comma-separated. So the `father_dictionary` should be:

```
father_dictionary = {
'Dict1':{'a':'1', 'b':2, 'c':3},
'Dict2':{'a':'4', 'b':5, 'c':3}}
```

Also, you forgot to close a bracket in the `mother_dictionary`:

```
mother_dictionary = {
'Dict3':{'a':'6', 'b':7, 'c':3}}
```

Now let's move to the problem, *to solve your problem*, you can try using the [`update()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) method from dictionaries:

```
father_dictionary.update(mother_dictionary)
```